# QtWebEngine, How to Save Cookies in C++/Qt6.2.4?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

Since I change Qt5 to Qt6 for my app,

What worked for Qt5 (to save the cookies, I followed this thread [QT 5.6 QWebEngine doesn't save cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336396/qt-5-6-qwebengine-doesnt-save-cookies)),

Doesn't work now :

```cpp
    QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::ForcePersistentCookies);
    QWebEngineProfile* defaultProfile = QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile();

    defaultProfile->setHttpCacheType(QWebEngineProfile::DiskHttpCache);
    defaultProfile->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::ForcePersistentCookies);
    QHttpPart* header = new QHttpPart;
    header->setRawHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");

    defaultProfile->setCachePath(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::CacheLocation));
    defaultProfile->setPersistentStoragePath(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation));
```

I need to save Cookies.

Comment: What does it mean not working? Could you give more detail, in which folder are you looking for the saved cookies?

Comment: Folders, there doesn't create, before to delete the Qt5 folder, the folders of cache and cookies didn't loaded.

Comment: if I add this :   
```qt
  
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);  

    QNetworkDiskCache *diskCache = new QNetworkDiskCache(this);  
    diskCache->setCacheDirectory(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::CacheLocation));   

    manager->setCache(diskCache);   

```   

a Cache folder created, but cookies were not saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is :

```cpp
    QWebEngineProfile *profile = new QWebEngineProfile(QString::fromLatin1("MyApplication.%1").arg(qWebEngineChromiumVersion()));  // unique profile store per qtwbengine version
    QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage(profile); // page using profile
    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView();

    view->setPage(page);
    view->setUrl(AccueilUrl);
    view->setZoomFactor(1.2);

    setCentralWidget(view);
```